# Is video downloaded every time I play a video in flutter by fetching it from firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, video-streaming, firebase-storage

So, I have a 35mb video file in firebase storage. So, I wanted to know that whenever I play the video using the url as shown in my code. Will it take 35mb internet/cellular data while watching it? or mobile/cellular data used is less while playing the video? If it is 35mb then how can i reduce the usage of the data used to play video. Just like youtube videos consume less data while watching when compared to uploading..

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'firebase video url')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
```

And showing video like this:-

```
Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search it looks like `VideoPlayerController.network` doesn't do any caching.

There's a long standing request and discussion to [add network cache functionality to video_player](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28094) on its Github repo, and some folks recently pointed to this widget: [cached_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player#-readme-tab-)

Comment: I too have used it. But the question is that whenever user plays the video for first time then will the mobile/cellular data or internet usage will be of 35 mb?

Comment: So your question is not about *caching*, but about *streaming* then?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+storage+play+streaming+video+flutter?